# Can you tell why this main class can't be found in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I've started a new app in Eclipse like I've done probably a couple dozen times now. I'm getting the message:

Error: Main method not found in class net.massstreet.ProcessWeatherData, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)

The last time I dealt with this, it was a minor syntax error. When I tried to do that fix here, I still got the message. When I tried to copy paste some known working code, that didn't fix it either. Take a look at the following and see if you can tell where I'm going south.

```
package net.massstreet

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j._

object ProcessWeatherData {

 def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set the log level to only print errors
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val spark = SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("IoT-With-Satori")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

    val weatherDF = spark
    .readStream
    .format("socket")
    .option("host", "localhost")
    .option("port", 9090)
    .load()

    //import spark.implicits._

    weatherDF.printSchema()



  }

}
```

Since I wasn't getting anywhere, I tried to simplify it and I still got the error with the following:

```
package net.massstreet

object Test extends App {
  println("hello world")
}
```

I don't even understand how you can mess that up but there it is.

I've set the run configurations. The files are in the proper folder. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: you are running a wrong file. did you run ProcessWeatherData or Test ?

Comment: Both. When I run test I get simply: Error: Could not find or load main class net.massstreet.Test

Comment: Oh hang on. There is a problem with my Scala version....

Answer (score 0):

I didn't notice an error notification in the Problems tab. I was running Scala 2.12 and Spark is asking for 2.11.